# los cálculos con números reales no son correctos en Delphi

Tags: delphi

estoy haciendo unos cálculos con números reales y no me están saliendo bien, pues lo he comparado con MS-Excel y los resultados son distintos.
Cuando hago esos cálculos en la función Rotate2D, el valor de X es correcto pero el valor de Y (resaltado a la izquierda) me sale incorrecto. Y así cuando calculo los demás valores, se van distorsionando drásticamente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando hago lo cálculos de esta otra manera,ambos valores X e Y son correctos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que los valores de la segunda imagen son correctos porque los he comparado con Excel, allí tengo los valores para X e Y correctos, pero yo quiero calcularlos en tiempo de ejecución en mi programa.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor si me pueden ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: Me olvidaba, estoy usando Delphi 10.2.

Comment: Las líneas en el programa de delphi se ejecutan en orden. La línea y := (c*y) + (s*x) se ejecuta justo después de que hayas asignado un nuevo valor a x en la línea anterior, por lo tanto este nuevo valor de x es el que se usa para hacer el cálculo y no el valor que pasaste como parámetro, por eso te da un resultado erróneo.

Comment: Gracias, creo que ya entendí el problema. Saludos.

Comment: @Pablo, tu comentario debieras publicarlo como respuesta, pues es lo correcto. El valor de la variable X es cambiado antes de su uso en el cálculo de Y y por eso los resultados son erróneos.

Comment: @Jose, no publiques imagenes del código. Publica el código como tal, no solo es más legible, sino que permite copiar y pegar el código para hacer pruebas y correcciones. Si lo publicas como código, el sitio respeta la identación y hace el resaltado de sintaxis.

Comment: @jachguate no lo publiqué como respuesta porque creo que una errata, o algo tan básico como el orden de ejecución de las líneas de código no hace que merezca la pena conservar la pregunta. Por eso reporté la pregunta pero hice un comentario para no dejar a quien preguntó a ciegas.

Comment: @Pablo, yo creo que toda pregunta dentro del tema, que tiene una respuesta clara, pertenece al sitio, y más importante es que puede servir de ayuda para alguien más en el futuro. Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate no se me puede ocurrir cómo esta pregunta podría servir a nadie en el futuro. En stackoverflow principal, las preguntas cuyo único problema era un error tipográfico son cerradas, porque es improbable que sean útiles a un visitante futuro.

Comment: @jachguate esas preguntas son cerradas con "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.". No veo el equivalente aquí, supongo que es un cambio que falta por migrar.